# I tried to install package from github but I get requirement parse error

Tags: python, terminal, bayesian

```
pip install get+get://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkBayes/blob/master/code/thinkbayes.py
```

```
pip install get+https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkBayes/blob/master/code/thinkbayes.py
```

I tried this in my terminal and I'm a windows user 
[github link for package](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkBayes/blob/master/code/thinkbayes.py)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out .. I users a text editor and copied the code and I saved the file as .py and saved it in the same directory where my main file is saved and used ''' import filename as something ''' . I was able to use the code from the file I got from github